# Changing a variable outside the scope of a method in Java

Tags: java, variables, methods, scope

So I'm trying to change the value of a minimum and maximum guess (with the actual guess being made by a random number generator) in order to stop the program from guessing the same number twice.

I have a method that makes a guess but also tries to set a lowest and highest guess which then changes when the method is used again

```
public static int takestab (int low, int high) {  
    int estimate;
    estimate = (low + (int)(Math.random() * ((high - low) + low)));

    if (estimate < number) {
        lowestguess = estimate;
    }
    else if (estimate > number) {
        highestguess = estimate;
    }
    return estimate;
}
```

Also, these are the vars I have outside of the method scope:

```
    int lowestguess = 1;
    int highestguess = 100;
```

So by running that method, the guess could be 50 and the actual number could be 60. if that's the case, then "lowestguess" becomes 50 so that the function can't guess any lower than 50.

When I try it this way, the cmd prompt says that it cant find the matching symbol.

Any ideas?

Comment: In which scope are those other variables? Either make them static or wrap them in a Class instance you modify in the method.

Comment: you can't use instance variables in a static method.

Comment: Although though some of the answers and comments address the probably cause, please include the error that you're getting when you try to compile.  It's probably a bit more descriptive than simply "cant find the matching symbol".  The answers will be more useful if they can explain how the message indicates the problem.

Comment: -The scope is in the main class
-Understood. removed the static from my method and it works fine now
- Sorry, didn't think about that one. Will do so in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `lowestguess` is an `instance` variable but your trying to access through a `static` method.

**Options**

- pass the lowestGuess as a non-primitive (Object) to the method.
- use a non-static method
- make lowestGuess be static

**Passing lowestGuess**

Example:

```
public static int takestab(int low, int high, Integer Lowest)
```

This allows you to also make changes to Lowest as it is *by reference*.

**Non Static Method**

Change method to  `public int takestab(int low, int high)`

**Change LowestGuess to static**

You should be careful in multi-threaded environments with this option.

---

**See:**

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/407266/java/java/Static-method-refer-instance-variable
- http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-does-a-static-method-access-instance-variables/31
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

---

Finally, if you were programming in an IDE such as eclipse you would have error highlighting in which errors such as this become obvious faster.

Comment: They all worked a treat. Can't upvote yet so thank you for the thorough advice. I'm using DrJava but I'm not too familiar with other IDEs yet. Just starting on my Java journey.

Answer (score 2):

`lowestguess` is an instance variable, it cannot be accessed without creating an instance. If you want to use it inside the `static` method then either you create an instance of your class and then use `lowestguess`, or if it makes sense then turn `lowestguess` as `static`.

The reason why `non-static` members are not allowed to be used in a `static` way is that, the memory initialization of instance variables happen when the object is created. And a `static` method can be called without creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

A `static` method can only use static members (and local var of course). Your members `lowestguess` & `highestguess` should therefore be declared as `static`.