# Why is an integer resetting to 100 when it should update to something different

Tags: java, variables, loops, methods, scope

The wall of code below should change the value of "lowestguess" and "highestguess" any time the loop runs through. Ideally, it's meant to lower the highest guess from 100 and raise the lowest guess from 1 so that the program can't guess a lower or higher number than it has already guessed (reducing the amount of loops it takes to complete the program.

However, each time it runs the "takestab" function, the lowestguess and highest guess always reset back to their defaults, 1 and 100 respectively. No idea what's going on here seeing as I'm not getting any errors.

Is it possible that because the methods here are private, they don't update the variables outside of their respective scopes?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AIGuessing
{
    public static void main(String[]args) 
    {
        //DECLARATIONS*
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        int guess;
        int guesses = 0;
        int lowestguess = 1;
        int highestguess = 100;

        //code
        System.out.println("Welcome!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number for the AI to guess");
        number = inputReader.nextInt();

        //computer tries to guess number
        do
        {
            guesses++;
            guess = takestab(lowestguess, highestguess, number);
            System.out.println("\"I guess " +guess+ ".\"");
        }while(guess != number);

        if(guess == number)
        {
            System.out.println("WOO! I got it!");
        }

        if(guesses >= 1 && guesses ==2)
        {
            System.out.println(guesses + " guesses? I..AM...GOD!!!!");
        }
        else if(guesses >= 3 && guesses <= 5)
        {
            System.out.println(guesses + " guesses? Hooray! I'm as average as gravy!!!");
        }
        else if(guesses >= 6 && guesses <= 8)
        {
            System.out.println(guesses + " guesses? I only guess when I'm drunk");
        }
        else if(guesses >= 9)
        {
            System.out.println(guesses + " guesses? Bugger me... turn me into scrap");
        }
        //end code
    }

    public static int takestab(Integer lowestguess, Integer highestguess, Integer number)
    {  

        int estimate;
        estimate = estimate(lowestguess, highestguess);
        System.out.println("Estimate is: "+estimate+".");

        if(estimate < number && estimate > lowestguess)
        {
            lowestguess = estimate;
            barkchange(lowestguess, highestguess, estimate);
        }
        else if(estimate > number && estimate < highestguess)
        {
            highestguess = estimate;
            barkchange(lowestguess, highestguess, estimate);
        }
                return estimate;
    }

    //function to generate and return a random number
    public static int estimate(int low, int high)
    {
        int comGuess;
        comGuess = (low + (int)(Math.random() * ((high - low) + low)));
        return comGuess;
    }

    //function to 'bark' the changes of lowest and highest guesses
    public static void barkchange(Integer lowestguess, Integer highestguess, Integer guess)
    {
        System.out.println("Current guess is: "+guess+".");
        System.out.println("Lowest guess is: "+lowestguess+".");
        System.out.println("Highest guess is: "+highestguess+".\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realsied that in the method "estimate" that my inputs were incorrectly named. I changed them to the variable names lowestguess and highestguess but nothing different happened.

Comment: quick comment - may/may not cause any issues, but generally it is poor style to have a variable name that is the same as a function name. consider `getEstimate()` or `int estimataion`.

Comment: please format the code

Comment: `lowestguess` within `takestab` is *not* the same as `lowestguess` within `main`. Just because two variables share the same name doesn't mean that they *are* the same.

Comment: It is just bad idea to cast the Math.random() to int and say you receive the same value. Math.random returns double and if you cast to int you always get one value (most of the times 0). Prefer using Random class to generate the random value, else use double value of Math.Random and do not cast to int

Comment: Unless you have reason to mix them (and I don't see any), you should pick either `int` (primitive) or `Integer` (object) and stick with it. It won't really make a difference, but it's more coherent and easier to follow.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - it would appear that he did it that way because of the previous [question (link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898701/changing-a-variable-outside-the-scope-of-a-method-in-java) he asked.

Comment: Just a heads up, your `if` statement to (presumably) check whether the number was guessed in one or two tries is incorrect. It will only evaluate to true if `guesses` equals `2`. Your second comparison operator should be `<=`, not `==`.

Comment: @JamesT along those lines, the whole thing could be refactored to use less-than operators rather than pointlessly checking if it is less than X and greater than y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer is an immutable object.

```
lowestguess = estimate;
```

At this line(and the one for `highestguess`), you're changing the local copy of lowestguess and not the one that you passed into it.

The most simple solution in this case, is to declare lowestguess and highestguess "globally" (static).

Above your main put

```
static int highestGuess = 100;
static int lowestGuess = 1;
```

Then, you can remove the parameters to your method, and you don't have to pass them in anymore. You can reference the static ones directly.

An aside for the nitpickers: I used "globally" here because there's no OO here. A static variable in this context is for all intents and purposes a global variable.